# Torrents while using Kodi

Tags: raspbian, kodi, deluge

Apologies for maybe a basic question : I've never really used any linux based stuff before, and only used the Pi for running straight into Kodi..

I've ordered a new Pi 4 (4gb), both will be used to run Kodi, one will have an external drive for video files..

Currently I download files on my PC and copy them over to the SMB drive on the Pi,  but i'm looking to sack off the PC..

It is possible to run rasbian on the Pi with a torrent client (Deluge for example)  while Kodi runs.  I've seen that it boots into one or the other...

Would I need to boot to Raspian to run torrents downloads, and then boot to Kodi to play them, or can they run simultaniously on the same Pi?

Many thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Kodi and torrent will work togather. But it will use a lot of you processor too. But yes it will run togather. To do that open the torrent client let it downlaod something , then open kodi and watch  videos.

Answer (score 1):

It will works with each other without any problem.

Some suggestions:

- Use rtorrent (and ruTorrent, if you want to manage torrents with web 
  interface) for much less CPU usage.
- I also recommend to use 17.4 version of Kodi (or newer if available).
- Use cooler/aluminium case    for Raspberry, because when the
  temperature reach 80 Celsius, it will reduce the CPU speed dramatically.